# Cell with formula and possible custom input

Tags: vba, excel

I have a cell with a formula based on another cell. This other cell is a data validation cell where the user can choose various options in a drop-down list.

As an example:

If the user chooses "A" in the drop-down list, then the formula calculates "1+1".

If the user chooses "B" in the drop-down list, the formula calcualtes "1+2".

The last option in the drop-down list is "Custom". If this option is chosen, then the user should insert a custom number.

However, if the user goes back and chooses "A" in the drop-down, the formula should be retained and calculate "1+1".

I have looked into some worksheet_change, but I have not been able to figure out how to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: assuming your cell with data validation is A2, then including an OR statement in your cell with a formula should do the trick, i.e. "IF(OR(A2="A",A2="Custom"),1+1,1+2)"

Comment: @JK2017, I believe that your formula would not work, as the OP mentioned that if Custom is selected, it should prompt the user for a custom number and your formula would give the same result if the user chose either A or Custom...

Comment: @Xabier - you are absolutely correct, sorry, I missed the bit where "Custom" needed user input. OK, so to keep this VBA-free, you can make cell B2 be the cell where user needs to provide value for "Custom" and then change the formula to: "=IF(A2="A",1+1,IF(A2="B",1+2,1+B2))"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Worksheet_Change event, you can do the following, this assumes that your Data Validation List is in cell B1 and you want the results in C1:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim CustomNumber As Variant
If Target.Address = "$B$1" Then
    Select Case ws.Range("B1").Value
        Case "A"
            ws.Range("C1").Formula = "=1+1"
        Case "B"
            ws.Range("C1").Formual = "=1+2"
        Case "C"
            ws.Range("C1").Formula = "=1+3"
        Case "D"
            ws.Range("C1").Formula = "=1+4"
        Case "E"
            ws.Range("C1").Formula = "=1+5"
        Case "Custom"
            CustomNumber = InputBox("Please enter a custom number", "Custom")
            If IsNumeric(CustomNumber) Then
                ws.Range("C1").Formula = "=1+" & CustomNumber
            Else
                MsgBox "Please enter a number", vbCritical = vbOKOnly
                Exit Sub
            End If
    End Select
End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

As per comments I've updated my answer to have only two Cases, either using a Custom number or using the value returned by a formula, this assumes your lookup formula is in A1, amend your code as required:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim CustomNumber As Variant
If Target.Address = "$B$1" Then
    Select Case ws.Range("B1").Value
        Case "Custom"
            CustomNumber = InputBox("Please enter a custom number", "Custom")
            If IsNumeric(CustomNumber) Then
                ws.Range("C1").Formula = "=1+" & CustomNumber
            Else
                MsgBox "Please enter a number", vbCritical = vbOKOnly
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Case Else 'if your lookup formula is in A1, then the code below will add one to the value from the formula
            ws.Range("C1").Formula = "=1+" & Val(ws.Range("A1").Value)
    End Select
End If
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

Following OP's further comments I've updated the code to include the lookup value returned by the formula:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim CustomNumber As Variant
If Target.Address = "$B$1" Then
    Select Case ws.Range("B1").Value
        Case "Custom"
            CustomNumber = InputBox("Please enter a custom number", "Custom")
            If IsNumeric(CustomNumber) Then
                ws.Range("C1").Formula = "=1+" & CustomNumber
            Else
                MsgBox "Please enter a number", vbCritical = vbOKOnly
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Case Else 'if your lookup formula is in A1, then the code below will add one to the value returned by the LookUp
            LookUpValue = "Ground type"
            LookUpTable = "Ground_type_table[#Alle]"
            ValueReturned = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(LookUpValue, LookUpTable, 4, False)
            ws.Range("C1").Formula = "=1+" & Val(ValueReturned)
    End Select
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am almost there with this. However, above was just an example, and in reality the formula is a lookup, so actually I just need 2 cases, either If "Custom" or anything else than "Custom", because then it looks up the correct value from a table.

Comment: @DFH I've updated my answer to reflect your comments, please could you also mark my response as an answer, if it has helped? Thanks. :)

Comment: Hello Xabier
It very much so is an answer. However, can you help me with my last little hurdle.
To keep with your example. First of all: "B1" is a data validation drop down list, and "C1" is the cell in which I want the result. However, "C1" is also the lookup cell. So if I choose "A" in the drop down list in "B1", then "C1" spits out "48" (or whatever the lookup is). If I choose "B" in the drop down list in "B1", then "C1" spits out "79". If I choose "Custom" in "B1", then "C1" should no longer use the lookup, but a custom entered number. I think we are close, but can you help me?

Comment: @DFH, It is probably best if the lookup formula was embedded within the code, so if you can provide the actual formula you are using, I can then update my answer to use the same formula whenever a value is other than "Custom" is selected.

Comment: In Danish:

=LOPSLAG(Ground_type;Ground_type_table[#Alle];4;falsk)

In english (with comma instead of semi-colon):

= vlookup(Ground_type,Ground_type_table[#Alle],4,false)

As you can see, I use defined named ranges and tables.

Comment: @DFH I've updated my answer once more to include the value from the lookup, I believe this should work as you expected, but do test it and let me know if you have any further issues. :)

Answer (score 0):

If it is allowed to hardcode your answer than I suggest (w/o VBA):

```
=IF(A1="A";1;IF(A1="B";2;A1))+1
```

Even better:
You have your dropdownlist in any other place and you have it done like a table:

A | 1

B | 2

Then you can have infinitely many options if you use a simply VLOOKUP like:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1;A2:B3;2;WRONG);A1)+1
```

This could be in cell B2.
**BUT** in this case you have a little different behaviour as you might want.